# It might be a DNS issue?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, dns, passwords

I'm new to linux.

Below is the issues that I have trouble with. (**Ubuntu 17.04**)

1. Root Password: I don’t know the root password, so I login as user; “$sudo -i”, and then “$passwd” to change the root password. It shows password updated successfully. However, when I tried to login as root@beta.ucmerced.edu, it shows permission denied. You can see the details from below pictures.

[root password update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5nao.png)

[root access denied](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plTyH.png)

2. Another problem I found is, when I tried to access the server at home, (without using school’s wifi UCM catNet) “ssh user@beta.ucmerced.edu” I can’t access it. I could only access the server by specifying its ip address “ssh user@169.236.184.83”. 
   How can I solve it. Thank you so much for your helps.

Answer (score 1):

Connecting with root to a server via ssh is usually disabled. 
There is an option in the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` file that define the `PermitRootLogin` parameter. If it is not set to yes, root password authentication via ssh is not possible. Note: It is a bad practice to enable this.

The server name is not a public name, so only the dns from your school can resolve it. If you can access your school dns server from internet, you can try to update the dns server on your network connection.

Answer (score 0):

1. [Check This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/44418/how-to-enable-root-login)
2. You need to Update the DNS records for beta.ucmerced.edu in Your DNS Server where the Domain Hosted